# PayU integration error for POST request- the mandatory filed 'furl' shows missing in payu response

Tags: spring, rest, payu

I did an integration with Payu through spring boot application.
The POST call has been made to Payu via rest template for the endpoint-'https://test.payu.in/_payment'​ along with all mandatory fields like merchant key, txnid, amount, productinfo, firstname, email, phone, surl, furl, hash​, however the payu response shows the field
furl is missing in request body.

Here, hash is generated by MessageDigest SHA-256 algorithm with hashSequence -key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|||||||||||salt"​

Find the below details for controller code and postman request:

Postman request:

```
  POST /payment/payu HTTP/1.1
  Host: localhost:8080
  Authorization: 3yFfqME/WIdeDKJdsdewSeDVFz3RYZMCDgWsM=
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
         
firstname=Swati&phone=9899999999&productInfo=Donation&amount=800&email=xyz@gmail.com&furl=http://localhost:8080/payment/payment-response-failure&hash=4bcb0d64d85d47ab89ab90372b14b5484451aaecf3d325df9f2c5ff54a9704d5a89bce9f69bcf80bd6854006eea070858b06d7aa9d94956223ae3ea82&key=auJL3I4R&txnId=Dev75e75f95d0b3&surl=http://localhost:8080/payment/payment-response
```

Error Description

```
SORRY!We were unable to process your payment</h2>
Error Reason
            Mandatory parameters which must be sent in the transaction are:
            key, txnid, amount, productinfo, firstname, email, phone, surl, furl, hash
            
            The parameters which you have actually sent in the transaction are: 
            key, txnid, amount, productinfo, surl, hash, firstname, email, phone
```

Your help would be more appreciated !!

Comment: Added mandatory parameter in Post call request that is "service_provider=payu_paisa", along with other mandatory parameter and it is not included in  hash. Still it didn't worked out.

Answer (score -1):

generate the url with UTF-8.It may work

Comment: Hi Hemanth, Thank you for your reply.
The issue has been resolved, There was inconsistency in hash generation. 
Cross verified the generated hash value from code with the value generated by the tool https://miniwebtool.com/sha512-hash-generator/.